# Solving the ODE $(y')^2 = c_{1} y^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{y^9}}\right) - k$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have the following 1st order, nonlinear ODE:
$$(y')^2 = c_{1} y^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{y^9}}\right) - k$$
where  $c_1$, $c_2$, and $k$ are all constants.

In principle, I know how to solve 1st order ODEs if they are separable but is this one, I tried but didn't figure it out.

Is there a way to get an analytical solution for this equation? Appreciating hints and tips.

Answer (score 0):

We write equation in the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{ c_{1} y^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{y^9}}\right) - k}
$$

This is the equation which does not contain independent variable. So, we can rewrite it as the equation which does not contain desired function
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\pm \sqrt{ c_{1} y^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{y^9}}\right) - k}}
$$
and integrate it
$$
x(y) = C \pm \int \frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{ c_{1} \xi^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{\xi^9}}\right) - k}},
$$
where $C$ is some constant.

But the last formula does not represent all solutions. Your equation has extra solutions $y(t) = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is root of equation $c_{1} \alpha^2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{c_{2}}{\alpha^9}}\right) - k = 0$. These solutions can be singular.

The differential equation is solved, and the problem turned into the problem of calculating indefinite (or definite) integrals.